# Cocos2D-X : Parsing list of objects from a TMX file, migrating code from version 2.X to version 3.X

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x

I am new to Cocos2D-X and have been trying to learn it for the past couple months now. I am trying to create a sample game from the book *Cocos2d-x Game Development Blueprints* and in this particular chapter it's explaining how to create a game using tiled map.

I Need help parsing a list of objects from a TMX file, I am trying to update the code from version 2.X to version 3.X, because I get compile errors. I need to change the deprecated CCArray and CCDictionary into the new cocos::Vector and Map in the following code

```
void GameWorld::CreateTiledMap()
{
// generate level filename
char buf[128] = {0};
sprintf(buf, "level_%02d.tmx", GameGlobals::level_number_);
// create & add the tiled map
tiled_map_ = CCTMXTiledMap::create(buf);
addChild(tiled_map_);

// get the size of the tiled map
columns_ = (int)tiled_map_->getMapSize().width;
rows_ = (int)tiled_map_->getMapSize().height;

// save a reference to the layer containing all the bricks
bricks_layer_ = tiled_map_->layerNamed("Bricks");

// parse the list of objects
CCTMXObjectGroup* object_group = tiled_map_->objectGroupNamed("Objects");
CCArray* objects = object_group->getObjects();
int num_objects = objects->count();

for(int i = 0; i < num_objects; ++i)
{
    CCDictionary* object = (CCDictionary*)(objects->objectAtIndex(i));

    // create the Hero at this spawning point
    if(strcmp(object->valueForKey("name")->getCString(), "HeroSpawnPoint") == 0)
    {
        CreateHero(ccp(object->valueForKey("x")->floatValue(), object->valueForKey("y")->floatValue()));
    }
    // create an Enemy at this spawning point
    else if(strcmp(object->valueForKey("name")->getCString(), "EnemySpawnPoint") == 0)
    {
        CCPoint position = ccp(object->valueForKey("x")->floatValue(), object->valueForKey("y")->floatValue());
        CCPoint speed = ccp(object->valueForKey("speed_x")->floatValue(), object->valueForKey("speed_y")->floatValue());
        CreateEnemy(position, speed);
    }
    // create a Platform at this spawning point
    else if(strcmp(object->valueForKey("name")->getCString(), "PlatformSpawnPoint") == 0)
    {
        CCPoint position = ccp(object->valueForKey("x")->floatValue(), object->valueForKey("y")->floatValue());
        CCPoint speed = ccp(object->valueForKey("speed_x")->floatValue(), object->valueForKey("speed_y")->floatValue());
        CreatePlatform(position, speed);
    }
    // save the point where the level should complete
    else if(strcmp(object->valueForKey("name")->getCString(), "LevelCompletePoint") == 0)
    {
        level_complete_height_ = object->valueForKey("y")->floatValue();
    }
}
}
```

I have tried converting it myself, but have been unsuccessful.
I am having trouble converting the CCArray to cocos::Vector,
but mainly changing the CCDictionary to cocos::Map. Can someone Please help me?

Comment: What are the errors? Can you please show us what you have tried to change and why it has failed?

Comment: @rhughes I get an error at CCArray* objects = object_group->getObjects(); and it says "No viable conversion from 'ValueVector' (aka 'vector<cocos::Value>') to 'CCArray *" I think getObjects() is no longer part of CCArray ,  and when i change CCArray* objects = object_group->getObjects(); to use the auto keyword i get an error at CCDictionary* object = (CCDictionary*)(objects->objectAtIndex(i)); saying : Cannot cast from type 'value_type' (aka 'cocos2d::Value') to pointer type 'cocos2d::__Dictionary *'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d-x has many tests, which is very helpful.  From `\tests\cpp-tests\Classes\TileMapTest\TileMapTest.cpp`:

```
auto map = TMXTiledMap::create("TileMaps/test-object-layer.tmx");
addChild(map, -1, kTagTileMap);

CCLOG("----> Iterating over all the group objets");

auto group = map->getObjectGroup("Objects");
auto& objects = group->getObjects();
for (auto& obj : objects)
{
    ValueMap& dict = obj.asValueMap();

    float x = dict["x"].asFloat();
    string name = dict["name"].asString();
}
```

Comment: Please can you apply your answer to the OP's question.

Comment: But I think this code snippet has clearly demonstrated how to get object group and objects from tmx files and then parse those objects. @rhughes